# IE-Bug with JQuery-Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, bxslider

i've added a JQuery Slider to my page (BXSlider) which works fine on nearly every page (in every browser) except this one in IE (7 & 8).

the images within the slider get loaded but than it shows a large blank space instead of the slided table (yes, it needs to be a table at this point)!

sorry for the posted link but i can't figure this one out and i don't know which code i should add in here... is it a CSS problem or JQuery/Javascript related?

i hope somebody can point me the right direction…

thanks alot,
Jochen

Comment: Why does it have to be a table, the script produces incorrect html because of this. The bxslider wraps to divs outside of the td which contains your image, so you have a table > tr > div > div > td, this might be the reason for the ie "bug", well in this case it's not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above. The way you implement the slider it produces incorrect html. The bxslider wraps two divs outside of the td which contains your images, so you get a HTML-structure like this: **table > tr > div > div > td**, and that is the reason IE has problems - and the browser is right with that. If you can't get rid of the table (which I would prefer) do the following:

Modify your HTML of the slider table like this:

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="bx-box">[.. YOUR LINKS AND IMAGES .. ]</div>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In JS do this:

```
$(function(){
    // change your your selector to the nested div container
    // and tada it works in ie too.
    $('td .bx-box').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: true
    });
});
```

Now the code stays valid after the bxSlider added the wrapper divs around it and the slider shows up cross browser. You'll find a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EYnAM/). And do yourself a favor, validate your code, there are more errors inside (double closing a tags and other), this can cause the strangest layout behaviours.

Comment: Was writing something very similar to this but there's no point now. Have an upvote.